# how to put a string in a char stack and print it out? c++

Tags: c++

I am passing a string to my function, and the function is supposed to use that string to put individual chars in a stack. Then the stack is supposed to spit it back out (Since it's a stack it should be reversed). For example if my string is hello, it should print "olleh". But instead I'm getting ooooo. I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm setting ch equal to a different character every time but I'm not sure how to input those character in a different way.

```
void Stack::function2reverse(string myString) {

    int countItIt = 0;
    int sizeOfString = myString.size();
    char Ch ;
    for (int i= 0; i< sizeOfString; x++)
    {
        Ch = myString[x];
        stack.push(Ch);
        countIt ++;

    }

    while (countIt != 0)
    {    
        cout << Ch;
        stack.pop();
        countIt --;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cout << Ch;` - you print the same character every time (the last one entered, so `'o'`).

Instead, print the top character in the stack: `std::cout << stack.top()`.

`std::stack` keeps track of its own [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/size), so you don't need to worry about that either. Then you can replace your print loop with:

```
while (!stack.empty()) {
    std::cout << stack.top();
    stack.pop();
}
```

And of course, the Standard Library provides a [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function anyway, so if this was not just an exercise in learning about `std::stack`, you could use that (and I can think of several other things to do as well, depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve):

```
std::string s = "hello";
std::reverse(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
// s now contains "olleh"
```

You may also want to read up on [why `using namespace std;` is a bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191)

Comment: oh got i! Thank you!! Oh I didn't know that. I will read more about that. Thanks!